# CSS flexbox / jquery: Auto gutter size

Tags: jquery, css, grid, flexbox

I'ms trying to build a responsive grid-list. The elements got a fixed height (300px) and width (120px). The space between the elements should be auto but have a minimum size of 20px.

This is my current CSS:

```
.folder-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.folder-list li {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

I got this result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdPEX.png)

But it should looks like this:

[It should looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2ufP.jpg)

Is there a way using CSS and jQuery to make it real?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdPEX.png), but when I added 3 small CSS properties (`flex-wrap`, `justify-content`, and `margin`), I got [this](http://codepen.io/krabbypattified/pen/KWXQVa). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks! The second row should aligned on the left. In your version its centered horizontally.

Comment: @JonasLoerken remove the "justify-content" entry and it will align left

Comment: @JonasLoerken it is. It is just wrapping the next item to the next row b/c there is no more available space available to fit the element. You can also change the width to 100vw instead of 100% so it takes up the entire viewport width